# what is this base: means? is it a standard c++ key word

Tags: c++

The code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : public A {
    void foo() override { base:foo(); }
};

void main() {
    A* p = new B();
    p->foo();

    delete p;
}
```

what is the 'base:' means? is it a standard key word in c++?

platform: win10 + vs2015 update3;

project type: win32 console project;

Comment: If the code is as shown, `base:` would be a label that could be referenced by a `goto` statement. However, that would be a pointless label, so something tells me you aren't showing us the real code.

Comment: `base:` is merely a label; could just as well write `xyz: foo();`. As written, `B::foo` enters infinite recursion. It does not call `A::foo`, if that's what you were hoping for.

Comment: All your `base:` are belong to us. Take off every `z->ig()`.`for(;GREAT_JUSTICE;) { Move(z->ig()); }`.

Comment: Guys, I'm just curious with this question - was commentators solutions tags (i.e. goto label)  wiped out from code block, or I've forgot cpp completely? I just cannot understand first two comments

Comment: @Brian actually it is the real code.the reason is that a label can be called automatically。the output of "void main(){label:std::cout<<123<<std::endl;}" is 123.

Comment: @code_farmer The label is redundant if there is no `goto` that jumps to it. You could just remove the `label:` part and that statement would still execute in the same way.

Comment: IIRC, the fact that C++ doesn't have a `super` or `base` keyword like other languages is related to multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A somewhat known idiom would involve something like

```
struct B : public A {
    typedef A base;
    void foo() override { base::foo(); }
};
```

What you have there looks superficially similar, but it is not that. In your case `base:` is just a label, which affects nothing. Unless the code you presented is an intentional puzzle/joke, it might actually be an attempt to reproduce what I posted above by a person who just doesn't rememebr all the details.

In any case, `base` is not a keyword in C++ (and is not a keyword in VS2015 either).

Comment: I agree with your answer, but, does it means problem in questioner code block, or something else? I hadn't coded in C++ for a long while, although in doubt something like this was (i.e. your suggestion without patch applied to source) was introduced to standard

Comment: @RobertColumbia I'm just curious comparing the difference between questioner code block and solution suggested. Why is that a problem? Nothing like "few lines were skipped" was mentioned anywhere

Comment: I not that dumb in C/C++ to understand the logic behind this questtion or answer, but it seems more like some preedited crap to me at the moment, honestly. Why does base::foo() overrides _A_ but not std::cerr, for example ?

Comment: @AnT It would be great if you can explain some logic why you had resolved this question the way you did (excluding obvious reasons). Minimal effort (aka Okham principle) basis, or something  else? While your solution is perfectly fine to me, I understand why you suggested it, I cannot formulate some determined algorithm to it... why it is so in general?

Comment: this is a puzzle my friend provided to me.

Answer (score 2):

`base` is not a keyword in C++. It's just an ordinary identifier with no special meaning.

If the code is exactly what you've shown us, then the `base:` is a goto label -- and completely pointless, since there are no references to it. You can demonstrate this yourself by (temporarily) adding `goto base;` after `base:foo();`. (I just tried it myself and didn't get any additional diagnostics. Of course that would be an infinite loop.)

It's likely that the author of the code didn't intend it to be a goto label, and might have thought that `base` would refer to the parent class. Perhaps `base:` was a typo for `base::` (which would be an error -- perhaps `base` is a keyword in some other language)?

It's impossible to be sure what the author intended. The use of `void main()`, which is illegal in C++ (it needs to be `int main()`) suggests that the author doesn't know C++ very well. He or she probably tried to do something that refers to the parent class, wrote it incorrectly, and happened by chance to write something that happens to compile.

Comment: struct base{...foo()...} struct derived:public base{....base:foo()....}

Comment: @code_farmer: So in the original code, `base` is the name of a class. Why on Earth did you not mention that in the question? The question needs to include the actual code you're asking about. (Depending on what the `...` stands for, the `base:` is probably still a goto label.) Read this: [mcve]